# Linux Fedora swift symbol lookup error

Tags: linux, swift, fedora

I'm trying to get swift working on my Fedora 22. I've followed the official instructions (https://swift.org/getting-started/#installing-swift). 
I'm able to use the swift REPL and execute a swift file without compiling it        with `swift main.swift`

swift.main content:

```
print("Hello, world!")
```

When I'm trying to compile it via: 
`swiftc main.swift -o main`
I'm getting the following error:

```
[christian@roodrallec Sources]$ swiftc main.swift -o main -v
Swift version 2.2-dev (LLVM 46be9ff861, Clang 4deb154edc, Swift 778f82939c)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -primary-file main.swift -target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -disable-objc-interop -color-diagnostics -module-name main -o /tmp/main-dd738b.o
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/bin/swift-autolink-extract /tmp/main-dd738b.o -o /tmp/main-739e5f.autolink
/usr/bin/clang++ /tmp/main-dd738b.o -L /home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux -lswiftCore @/tmp/main-739e5f.autolink -Xlinker -T /home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/x86_64/swift.ld -o main
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `uiter_setUTF8_55'
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `ucol_strcollIter_55'
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `uiter_setString_55'
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `ucol_next_55'
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `ucol_closeElements_55'
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `u_strToUpper_55'
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `ucol_strcoll_55'
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `ucol_open_55'
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `u_strToLower_55'
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `ucol_openElements_55'
/home/christian/Downloads/swift-2.2-SNAPSHOT-2015-12-01-b-ubuntu15.10/usr/lib/swift/linux/libswiftCore.so: undefined reference to `ucol_setAttribute_55'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is it, because the binaries are for Ubuntu? Or what did i miss?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/thawkins/fedora-swift

Comment: That looks nice, I will test it and tell you how it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, the errors indicate that there are some symbols, most likely functions, that are needed by Swift, but are not available in any of the libraries that are being used.  The function names aren't ringing the bell with me, so I cannot really tell how to resolve these particular errors.

I think at this point you might want to try building Swift from source as described here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/README.md.  Using Ubuntu binaries on Fedora is probably not a good idea.  Even if you get past these errors, something else is likely to come up later.

I haven't tried building Swift from source yet, so can't really share any experiences on that.

Comment: Yes, these symbols should be provided by the swift library. I just set up an Ubuntu 15.10 and it worked like a charm. Compiling from source will be my next attempt with Fedora, but for now i can experiment with my Ubuntu version.